# comparing coefficients between lmList and lmer

Tags: r, lme4

can anyone tell me why the slope coefficients deviate between those extracted from a lmer model with a random slope, and those from a lmList model fitted to the same dataset?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found the answer in Doug Bates' book on lme4. Paraphrasing... when the individual linear fit at the subject level is poor the linear mixed effects model coefficient tends to exhibit what is called “shrinkage” (see http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/lMMwR/lrgprt.pdf) towards the population level value (e.g. the fixed effect). In this case the uncertainty in the site-level coefficient is large (e.g. our confidence in our absolute estimate of its precise value is low), so in order to balance fidelity to the data, measured by the residual sum of squares, with simplicity of the model, the mixed-effects model smooths out the between-subject differences in the predictions by bringing them closer to a common set of predictions, but not at the expense of dramatically increasing the sum of squared residuals.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "shrinkage" might be a good thing assuming some degree of similarity among your subjects (or observational units), for example if you assume they are drawn from the same population, because it makes the model more robust to outliers at the individual level.

You can quantify the increase in the sum of squared residuals by computing an overall coefficient of determination for the mixed-effects model and the within-subject fits. I am doing it here for the `sleepstudy` dataset contained in the `lme4` package.

```
> library(lme4)
> mm <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), data = sleepstudy) # mixef-effects
> ws <- lmList(Reaction ~ Days |Subject, data = sleepstudy) # within-subject
> 
> # coefficient of determination for mixed-effects model
> summary(lm(sleepstudy$Reaction ~ predict(mm)))$r.squared
[1] 0.8271702
> 
> # coefficient of determination for within subjects fit
> require(nlme)
> summary(lm(sleepstudy$Reaction ~ predict(ws)))$r.squared
[1] 0.8339452
```

You can check that the decrease in the proportion of variability explained by the mixed-effects model respect to within-subjects fits is quite small `0.8339452 - 0.8271702 = 0.006775`.